# Copying a folder over with Shutil while saving to a file within it. What will happen?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shutil, copytree

Two different areas of my code deal with a directory.  One copies the directory every 6 minutes to a new location.  The other randomly will save to a file within the directory on rare occasion.  I used shutil.copytree for the directory copy and df.to_excel with Pandas to write to a *.ods in that folder.  I wrapped both with repeating Try and Excepts that loop 10 times with a .2 second pause.  My hope was if there was a syncronous collision that it would eventually succeed within the 2 seconds of retries via the try and excepts.   What happens if the shutil copies the folder while pandas is trying to write to a *.ods in the folder???  Will one wait for the other or will one corrupt data?

Comment: Do you use several processes in parallel (or some other concurrency)? I fail to understand how this could happen otherwise?

Comment: Depends on which point the race condition may occur, and on your *OS*. Generally, you should synch your accesses to avoid this kind of situations.

Comment: It is actually 240 subprocesses :/  On Windows

Comment: I think I need to just spend the time to make a mock test.  It is just a bit complex to mock up.  Normally I could have things communicate better, but I kind of was trapped in a spot in the code that it is not easy to get them to communicate.

Comment: ...bad stuff?
Basically, this race condition should be avoided at _reasonable_ cost; Look up options on locking the directory during read/write operations (mutex/semaphore/etc.).

Comment: I was using shutils yesterday to move large numbers files, and at one point in my testing, I was trying to delete a test folder while script was running but folder was locked. so you will face locking issues at OS level. you probably should implement custom locking logic and retries in different parts of your code to avoid failing completely.